# Error on storing xml data to sql table

Tags: java, android, sql, xml, arraylist

sorry question removed for modifications

Comment: Please reduce the large code dump to a minimal example.

Comment: that's the thing, the code is so interrelated, need to look at almost the entire code to fully get it. Main problem is in `onPostExecute()`. It seems my `services` list returned from `doInBackground()` is empty or it is in a different data type that cannot be directly stored into db

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Clijsters thanks..., makes sense.

Comment: @notyou I have reduced the code, it's better now or I remove further?